# Creating a chrome extension directory and saving files in it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filesystems

I want to create a local directory on user's machine for my extension and then store some files there. I read the docs and turns out we have access now with the [systemFileProvider API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/fileSystemProvider/#type-CreateDirectoryRequestedOptions). But there are no samples or examples on how this work, anyone has a link? Or just pointers? I don't want to go the local server route , I'd rather not use it if the API is capable of doing what I want.

Comment: This API is only for ChromeOS and it doesn't implement what you want. There is no such API for extensions. Solutions: 1) [File System Access API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/), 2) the deprecated virtual HTML5 FileSystem, 3) write an external utility and invoke it via nativeMessaging.

Comment: Isn't NativeMessaging also deprecated for manifestV3? For your first solution, I don't want the user's input since I will be downloading a lot of files and it's impractical. I'd rather write the files to the local directory implicitly.

Comment: NativeMessaging is not deprecated. The notice is about chrome apps.

Comment: I see, I'm trying the native messaging route since I don't want to display popup messages for every file (sol1 and sol2). Thank you.

Comment: @confusedstudent Did you find a solution? Would you mind answering your own question?

Comment: I would also be interested in the solution